# Hard surface modeling - topology problem

Tags: topology

Don't know why the problem occurs.

[image]

after smooth shading, this appears

[image]

I need an edge loop there for the sharp edge of the gun cut-out.

Comment: Try (in edit mode) select all, `mesh > normals > recalculate outside`.

Comment: tnx this works :D

Comment: How can I mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your normal directions have become mixed up. To solve, (in edit mode) select all, then pick  *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate outside*.